# How to enable secondary ethernet NIC card?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

I recently set up a new Ubuntu 20.04 install on an old PC of mine. It's running some docker containers just fine. However, its installed ethernet NIC doesn't support 1000 Mbps speed. I'd like to be able to take advantage of my home network speed, so I bought [this ethernet NIC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003CFATNI). I'm new to hardware modification, but I believe I installed it correctly. I just plugged it into a PCIe port. I can see that my PC recognizes it, but does not use it.

`lspci` shows `05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8161 (rev 15)`

`ip addr` shows new ethernet connection:

```
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:3f:8c:76:a2:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I restarted my PC a couple times, and realized that the NIC would not appear on `ipconfig`, only on `ipconfig -a`. After doing `sudo ipconfig enp5s0 up`, it would appear on `ipconfig`. What does this mean? How can I make it appear on boot so that I can use it as my primary connection?

The company does not offer an official Linux driver, but the Realtek r8168 driver [supposedly works](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/TxOJK4GB8LTGDB/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza). I installed it by updating the package lists to "universe" and  did `sudo apt update && sudo apt install r8168-dkms`. `lsmod` shows me that both r8169 (buggy driver) and r8168 (driver I want) are installed but not used by enp5s0:

```
r8168                 548864  0
r8169                  90112  0
```

I also blacklisted r8169 by adding it to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.
Still, `ethtool -i enp5s0` shows me that it's still "driver: r8169".

I've tried using nmtui, but it won't let me apply the connection to the device because 'the device is strictly unmanaged'. I googled this, but all that came up was changing a line in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf from managed=false to managed=true. Restarted network manager service but still `nmcli d` shows all devices as unmanaged. Not sure if related.

All in all, plugging in an ethernet cable to the new port is not working. I use SSH to manage this pc because it's headless, so I can't connect when I use that port. Perhaps I'll get a monitor and keyboard and see what the previous commands say when I plug in just to the new port. If anyone had a similar problem, please let me know. I appreciate any help

Edit:
Output of sudo dmesg -l emerg,alert,crit,err,warn: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7zp2MFg84g/

Edit:
output of @chili555's commands: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/25Rfdknr7p/

Comment: Please do a `sudo dmesg -l emerg,alert,crit,err,warn` and post the results.

Comment: Please run the following terminal commands: `tail -n5 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and: `lsmod | grep r816` and: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've posted the results on the body. @chili555 For the netplan yaml file, I had tried to configure a static IP for my other Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Did the static IP not work as expected? Does: `ip addr show` have an IP address for enp0s10? To be clear, id the old NIC card unplugged?

Comment: @chili555 the static IP is for my other ethernet NIC and it's working as far as I can see (Still the same IP). `ip addr show` does not show any IP address for my new NIC. I didn't unplug the old one, should I do so? I'd prefer to touch my PC as little as possible but if that's the problem then I will. If it is the problem, It seems kind of obvious now. dumb mistake on my part

Comment: Does the IP address on the old NIC differ from that shown in netplan? I thought that the intent was to use the new NIC because of its 1 gHz speed. You can't know if it's working correctly if it isn't even plugged in. Or are both plugged in?

Comment: Please join me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127043/chat-with-zackt-and-chili555

Comment: Yes, sorry for causing confusion, the intent is to use the new NIC due to its speed. I just mentioned that before I was also configuring a static IP for my old NIC before I installed the new one. Both NICs are plugged in. I'm using SSH to communicate with my server, so I can tell that when I only connect an Ethernet cord to the new NIC, I cannot connect. Only when I connect a cord to the old one, I can ssh into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions are to make sure that the new NIC will connect and get an IP address:

```
sudo dhclient -v enp5s0
```

Did it get an IP address? Confirm:

```
ip addr show
```

If it did, then amend the netplan file to use *only* enp5s0. Carefully follow the examples:
`cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml`

Netplan is strict about indentation, spacing, etc, so be cautious. Once the file is set, follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
```

And then:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

It ought to take immediate effect. Did the interface get the requested address? Check:

```
ip addr show
```

If so, you are all set and you can detach the ethernet cable from the old NIC.

Comment: Yep, this worked! Thank you again